# Таблица Пифагора без единицы

Tags: python, циклы, таблицы

Нужно вывести таблицу Пифагора для чисел от одного до девяти
мой код:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print(f' {i * j:2}', end=' ')
    print()
```

выводит:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

а должно выводить:

```
   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18
3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Подскажите, как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать *тернарный* оператор, мне кажется так менее громоздко код выглядит - без лишних строк и повторов кода:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        print(f' {"" if i == j == 1 else i * j:2}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 3):

просто добавьте один if

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 10):
        if i == 1 and j == 1:
            print(f'   ', end=' ')
        else:
            print(f' {i * j:2}', end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю еще вариант в одну строку:

```
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:>3}'.format(c * r if c * r != 1 else ' ')
                          for c in range(1, 10)]) for r in range(1, 10)]))
```